# how to generate random text from string of words

Tags: javascript

I have a string listing words/tokens like this:

```
input = "im ac ad af al ap ar de died cat",
```

how to generate randomized "words" output based on that, e.g.

```
output = "ac im al ad af ap ar cat de died",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution using `array.sort()`..
It is simpler than what is proposed in the duplicate link... but it does the work

```js
const input = "im ac ad af al ap ar de died cat";

console.log(input.split(' ').sort(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)) - 1).join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the array few times to shuffle.

```js
input = "im ac ad af al ap ar de died cat";
input = input.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
 let ind1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (input.length));
 let ind2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (input.length));
 [input[ind1], input[ind2]] =  [input[ind2], input[ind1]];
}

console.log(input.join(' '));
```